# How can I format a cell into a number within a Google Query?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell that is formatted as Time. However when I use that cell within a query and try to use an aggregator on it, it will tell me it can't be done because it's not a number. When I manually format the cell as a number it has no problems. Is there a way to tell the Google Query that it can use that column as a number?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before. I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I can share on solution I have used to aggregate time. Maybe it will give you an idea. Break the time into hrs, min, and sec and then those can be aggregated. Like this:

```
=query(query(A2:B8,"select hour(A), minute(A),second(A)"),"select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3)")
```